# Error shows up in server when using private_pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to use the private_pub gem for real-time updates in sample app so I can learn it and use it on the app I'm working on . But it always throws the following error when I type

```
rails s


shyam@shyam-SATELLITE-C50-B:~/Ajaxtry$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on 
http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub.rb:21:in `load_config': uninitialized constant YAML (NameError)
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub/engine.rb:8:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/shyam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/shyam/Ajaxtry/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

The thin server seems to be working fine. Would appreciate any help .
I'm using ruby -v 2.2.2p95 and rails 4.2.2

UPDATE:

I do not think that it is with either the private_pub gem or the Sync gem(I tried using Sync just to make sure). Its still showing the same error. Since it says YAML is an uninitialized constant, i checked the function storing the YAML load and it looks like the following:

```
#.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sync-0.3.5/lib/sync.rb 
def load_config(filename, environment)
  reset_config
  yaml = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(filename)).result)[environment.to_s]
  raise ArgumentError, "The #{environment} environment does not exist in #{filename}" if yaml.nil?
  yaml.each{|key, value| config[key.to_sym] = value }
  setup_logger

  if adapter
    setup_client
  else
    setup_dummy_client
  end
 end
```

Why doesn't ruby recognize that YAML?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps included in the `setup` part, that is adding `gem "private_pub" gem "thin"` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` followed by the generator `rails g private_pub:install` and starting the faye with `rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` ?

Comment: yes @PhilM. I followed exactly that but the above error showed up. This also seems to be an issue that's been reported here:https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/118

Comment: Aw, then I have no clue right at the moment, sorry.. :(

Comment: its cool Phil, hope to find help on the way :)

Comment: i tried using Sync instead too, but it throws up the same error. Now I'm thinking its not an issue with the gem , but my source file?

Comment: after removing private_pub gem application is running or not ? because if it is running after remove private_pub gem then try to use faye gem directly not private_pub.

Answer (score 1):

Private Pub does not work with Rails 4. It has been forked to this gem:

```
https://github.com/gregmolnar/chatter
```

See this thread and comment: https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/83#issuecomment-23869164